# How to set wait_timeout for MySQL in Play Java Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, connection, connection-timeout

I am using **Play framework 2.3.2**. My play application **leaks connection** after a **long idle time** (may be after 8 hours).

I want to set **wait_timeout** to MySQL in play java project. I know how to add in MySQL using `/etc/mysql/my.conf`. But I want to know to how can I do it into **application.conf** ?

Comment: You can also try [play-hikaricp](https://github.com/edulify/play-hikaricp.edulify.com) plugin and see if it has a better behavior for your scenario.

Comment: @marcospereira: I tried play-hikaricp. It throws error. Please check it out - https://github.com/edulify/play-hikaricp.edulify.com/issues/76

Comment: Try with the newest version, 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

In your application.conf you can add additional bonecp configurations,

```
# Idle max age
db.default.idleMaxAge=5 minute

# This sets the time for a connection to remain idle before sending a test query to the DB. 
# This is useful to prevent a DB from timing out connections on its end. 
db.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=2 minutes
```

For further information go through the play documentation,
[Play 2.3.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsJDBC)

[Bonecp with hibernate settings Jolbox](http://www.jolbox.com/index.html?page=http://www.jolbox.com/configuration.html)

Comment: Tried with above logic. It doesn't work. :( Any other help.

Comment: Mysql also has such configurations in their mysql.d file. Please do the same thing there as well.